# Why do I get an IllegalFormatPrecisionException when I try to format a String?

Tags: java, string-formatting

When I wrote a code in Java it showed the following exception

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatPrecisionException: 2".

I have no idea how to solve the problem.
Here is the code for reference (in main).

```
ool2 time=new ool2();
System.out.println(time.toMil());
```

Here is the method call in ool2.

```
public String toMil() {
    return String.format("%.2d:%.2d:%.2d",hr,min,sec);
}
```

oo2 code:

```
public class oo2 {

    private int hr,min,sec; 

    public void setTime(int h,int m,int s) { 
        hr= (h>=0&&h<24)?h:0; 
        min= (m>=0&&m<60)?m:0; 
        sec= (s>=0&&s<60)?s:0;
    }

    public String toMil() { 
        return String.format("%.2d:%.2d:%.2d",hr,min,sec); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could to please provide a full and formatted code off `oo2` and `main()` ?

Comment: Here is code of ool2 'private 
    int hr,min,sec;
public void setTime(int h,int m,int s){
        hr= (h>=0&&h<24)?h:0;
        min= (m>=0&&m<60)?m:0;
        sec= (s>=0&&s<60)?s:0;}
    public String toMil(){
        return String.format("%.2d:%.2d:%.2d",hr,min,sec);'

Comment: check documentation of [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html): "*For character, **integral**, and date/time argument types and the percent and line separator conversions, the precision is not applicable; if a precision is provided, an exception will be thrown.*" 1-precision is he number given after the point in the format string (`2` in your code) and is used for like for the number of digits after the decimal point, which is useless for `int` - probably you want to use `%2d`, without the decimal point, even `%02d` for leading zeros

Answer (score 2):

to formate time like `00:00:00` use the below

```
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hr, min, sec);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the *javadoc* of class [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)

> format specifiers for general, character, and numeric types have the
>   following syntax:
>   %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion

The only part you **have** to supply is *conversion*.

Also from the same *javadoc* regarding the *conversion*

> 'd'   integral    The result is formatted as a decimal integer

So the format specifier you need for `int` is `%d`, which you are correctly using, however an `int` does not have precision. A `float` or a `double` may have precision but `int` does not. So I guess what you want is *width* and not *precision*, hence you need to remove the `.` character and use the following

```
return String.format("%2d:%2d:%2d",hr,min,sec);
```

Note though, that this would print a single digit number - like 7 - with a leading space as in " 7". If you want leading zeros, then you need to add a zero before the 2 as in...

```
return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d",hr,min,sec);
```